# My photo application

Tags: android

I have a problem. I created a camera app. This app is working like this:
first you should take a picture and after you need to grant a permission and this picture will be set onto an ImageView. It's working, but if you click to close the camera, this app stops working. I don't know what should I do?

Code: https://gyazo.com/50453035c08f194fe9957971db142bef
Problem: https://gyazo.com/4df726655e52351f440445a701374b72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check resultCode in your OnActivityResult().

The reason is simple when you click cancel button the data is null but since you don't check the resultCode your app will get null pointer